# 'MyAppConfig' must supply a name attribute

Tags: python, django

i am try to run some piece of code when starting an apache server or django development server. I am using the AppConfig class to do this..(following [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig)).
But while starting the server i am get the following error.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: '{app_name}.apps.MyAppConfig' must supply a name attribute.

following is the sample code:

```
  from django.apps import AppConfig
  class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
       def ready():
           #my stuff
```

I don't have any idea about the error.

Answer (score 8):

The [docs you linked to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) tell you what `name` should be:

> **AppConfig.name**
>
> Full Python path to the application, e.g. `'django.contrib.admin'`.
>
> This attribute defines which application the configuration applies to. It must be set in all AppConfig subclasses.
>
> It must be unique across a Django project.

So if your app is call `app_name`, then you need to set `name = 'app_name'`.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
    
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'

    def ready(self):
        # my stuff
```

Comment: Was not working for me. The problem was in <app>.__init__.py where I had `<app>.apps.AppConfig` instead of `<app>.apps.<ChildAppConfig>`. Interesting is that django starts with no warning. The ChildAppConfig is silently not used :( - dj3.1

Comment: @mirek `<app>.apps.AppConfig` is a valid path, because you import it with `from django.apps import AppConfig`. It probably wouldn't be worth adding a check to Django unless it was a very common mistake.