# python django project hosting error on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, hosting

2022-07-03 04:54:11,060: Error running WSGI application
2022-07-03 04:54:11,078: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'user.apps.AppConfig' must supply a name attribute.
2022-07-03 04:54:11,078:   File "/var/www/atmadevrt99_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-07-03 04:54:11,078:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-07-03 04:54:11,078:
2022-07-03 04:54:11,078:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:
2022-07-03 04:54:11,079:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2022-07-03 04:54:11,080:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2022-07-03 04:54:11,080:
2022-07-03 04:54:11,080:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 239, in create
2022-07-03 04:54:11,080:     "'%s' must supply a name attribute." % entry
2022-07-03 04:54:11,080: ***************************************************
2022-07-03 04:54:11,081: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-07-03 04:54:11,081: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
2022-07-03 04:54:11,081: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-07-03 04:54:11,081: ***************************************************
2022-07-03 04:54:13,244: Error running WSGI application
2022-07-03 04:54:13,244: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'user.apps.AppConfig' must supply a name attribute.
2022-07-03 04:54:13,244:   File "/var/www/atmadevrt99_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2022-07-03 04:54:13,245:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246:
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246:   File "/home/atmadevrt99/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 239, in create
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246:     "'%s' must supply a name attribute." % entry
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246: ***************************************************
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-07-03 04:54:13,246: ***************************************************

Comment: did you look at the debugging help page clearly linked in the error message?

Comment: The problem seems to be this line: `ImproperlyConfigured: 'user.apps.AppConfig' must supply a name attribute`. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741672/myappconfig-must-supply-a-name-attribute) answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you need to modify wsgi appplication through the web page of pythonanywhere and change the name the of the project inside wsgi.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).